# Group representations and generators

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-presentation

could someone elaborate on the following:

A matrix representation of a group $G$ is a homomorphism $R:G\rightarrow GL_n$.

If a group $G$ is given by

$$\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\mid r_1,\dots,r_k\rangle$$

generators and relations and we have matrices $R_{x_1},\dots ,R_{x_n}$ that satisfy the relations, Then we may obtain a matrix representation $R:G\rightarrow GL_n$.

May someone elaborate on why the map is a homomorphism please?

Comment: Presentations are often defined by a universal property. You're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: @Shaun could you suplement the definition given by a universal property?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3255411/104041).

Comment: Also, only three dots are required for an ellipsis.

Comment: The map on the free group is a homomorphism. (Property of being free.) And the kernel of this homomorphism contains the $r_i$, so induces a homomorphism on the factor group $G$.

Comment: This is true for any target group. For any groups $G$ and $H$, where $G$ has a given presentation with generators and relations, the homomorphisms $G\to H$ correspond to choices of where to send the generators which satisfy the same relations.